# Pass row number as variable in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have:

1. a value of 5 in `B1`
2. I want to pass the number (5) in `B1` as a row variable, which will be read in conjunction with column `A` into another cell (say `C1`) as "=A(B1)" i.e. "=A5"

How would I do this?

Comment: Yashpal I rewrote this because it was unclear which is why `t.thielemans` found it hard to answer.

Comment: I am sorry, by mistake i rolled it back, and i don't how to revert my action. I am new to this. so it happened by mistake. Can you please do it again or revert back your change over it.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Assuming your row number is in `B1`, you can use `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & B1)
```

This takes a cell reference as a string (in this case, the concatenation of `A` and the value of `B1` - 5), and returns the value at that cell.

Comment: And, importantly for my purposes, you can use it as you'd expect: `=AVERAGE(A1:INDIRECT("A"&B1))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This should do the trick! :)

```
B1 =ROW(A5)
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/row.php

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question, not sure though, but if I have I will gracefully delete my answer.

Comment: It was a bit a tricky :) The question was more 'If I have a value cell `B1` (let's say 5), how to I find the value of the cell `A5`? Since the row number may change, `INDIRECT` lets you use whatever value is in that cell to indicate the row.

Comment: @RocketDonkey, Oh so he wanted `=A5` to become `=A(B1)`, and `B1 = 5`? Btw is there a quicker way to use the coding brakcets, because I always need to open help and copy them.

Comment: Exactly :) As for the coding brackets, you can use the backtick character (left of the 1 on my keyboard) to do a quick inline code highlight, or `Ctrl+K` to format a block in an answer/question.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use OFFSET:

Assuming the column value is stored in B1, you can use the following

```
C1 = OFFSET(A1, 0, B1 - 1)
```

This works by:

a) taking a base cell (A1)
b) adding 0 to the row (keeping it as A)
c) adding (A5 - 1) to the column

You can also use another value instead of 0 if you want to change the row value too.